# Users enter or select either One Value or Combination of Values or All Values in UI Search screen in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need a Stored Procedure which will give results when searching either with One value or any Combination of Values in UI screen.

**UI Screen:**

```
Emp ID: _____________   FirstName:_______________  LastName:_______________

Salary:___________ Org:_______________ Location:__________ Country:__________


                                   Search button        Cancel button
```

I'm not sure how to get the results when the User enters either one value or all values or combination of values in those fields and clicks on the Search button.

The data is coming from a table called Employee in Oracle database.

**Code:**

```
 Procedure search_emp(p_id    in NUMBER,
                      fname   in VARCHAR2,
                      lname   in VARCHAR2,
                      sal     in NUMBER,
                      org     in VARCHAR2,
                     location in VARCHAR2,
                     country  in VARCHAR2
                     cursor1  OUT REF CURSOR)

 BEGIN

 OPEN cur FOR

 select emp_id, fname,lname,sal,org,location,country from Employee;

 --- I'm not sure how to get the results when the User enters either one value or all values or combination of values in those fields.  
 END;
```

Please help.

Comment: Your procedure `search_emp` seems to be  **not** doing any "searching". It is simply selecting values passed  by the user's input from the Employee table. Maybe you're not showing us the complete query which has the information crucial to understand what you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter names you use for the procedure *look like* column names. I suggest you not to do that as you'll get unexpected results. For example, if you put it as `where fname = fname` (the first `fname` being column name and the second one a parameter), it'll be as if you wrote `where 1 = 1` (disregard nulls for this example); precede parameters' names with `p_` (or whatever you find appropriate). Also, always use table aliases (`e.` in my example).

Then, your code might look like this:

```
procedure search_emp (p_id        in     number,
                      p_fname     in     varchar2,
                      p_lname     in     varchar2,
                      p_sal       in     number,
                      p_org       in     varchar2,
                      p_location  in     varchar2,
                      p_country   in     varchar2,
                      cursor1        out ref cursor)
is
begin
   open cursor1 for
      select e.emp_id,
             e.fname,
             e.lname,
             e.sal,
             e.org,
             e.location,
             e.country
        from employee e
        where (upper(e.fname)    like '%' || upper(p_fname)    || '%'  or p_fname    is null)
          and (upper(e.lname)    like '%' || upper(p_lname)    || '%'  or p_lname    is null)
          and (e.sal             = p_sal                               or p_sal      is null)
          and (upper(e.org)      like '%' || upper(p_org)      || '%'  or p_org      is null)
          and (upper(e.location) like '%' || upper(p_location) || '%'  or p_location is null)
          and (upper(e.country)  like '%' || upper(p_country)  || '%'  or p_country  is null);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code. However, the user is entering the partial input parameter such as for country  param.. they tend to give 'RUS' and the stored procedure needs to get all the data of the country names containing 'RUS' or 'rus'. I tried the below query but am seeing errors in that. I used UPPER function with LIKE and OR operator.                                                                                            i'm getting PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid character . Please help

Comment: select e.emp_id, e.fname,e.lname, e.sal,e.org,e.location,e.country from Employee e  where (UPPER(e.fname)   like UPPER(%p_fname%)    or p_fname    is null) and (UPPER(e.lname)   like UPPER(%p_lname%)    or p_lname    is null)
 and (UPPER(UPPER(e.sal)      like UPPER(%p_sal%)      or p_sal      is null)
          and (UPPER(e.org)      like UPPER(%p_org%)      or p_org      is null)
          and (UPPER(e.location) like UPPER(%p_location%) or p_location is null)
          and (UPPER(e.country)  like UPPER(%p_country%)  or p_country  is null);

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my message by applying UPPER and LIKE where appropriate. Note that you have to concatenate the wildcard with the parameter. Also, LIKE doesn't make sense with numbers (such as P_SAL parameter).

Comment: No problem; I hope it'll help.